Can not find the tag library descriptor for "https://jakarta.ee/jsp/jstl/core"
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="https://jakarta.ee/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="CreateGroupServlet" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="groupName" placeholder="Enter group name" required>
        <button type="submit">Create Group</button>
    </form>
    
    <%-- Assuming group list is fetched from a servlet and set as a request attribute --%>
    <c:forEach items="${groups}" var="group">
        <div>
            <h3>${group.group_name}</h3>
            <form action="JoinGroupServlet" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="${group.group_id}">
                <button type="submit">Join Group</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
    
    
    <%-- Assuming requests are fetched and set as a request attribute --%>
    <c:forEach items="${requests}" var="req">
        <div>
            <p>${req.user_name} wants to join ${req.group_name}</p>
            <form action="ManageGroupRequestsServlet" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="${req.request_id}">
                <button type="submit" name="action" value="approve">Approve</button>
                <button type="submit" name="action" value="reject">Reject</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
    
    
    

</body>
</html>

<%@ taglib uri="https://jakarta.ee/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> //i am not able used this taglibenter image description here

while running the code
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message The absolute uri: [https://jakarta.ee/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [https://jakarta.ee/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:54)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:301)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:82)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:252)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:123)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:429)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:487)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1444)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:245)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:106)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:211)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Issue i have faced here,  Can not find the tag library descriptor for "https://jakarta.ee/jsp/jstl/core"
I am using tomcat 10.
i have download two jar file jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-3.0.1 jar  and jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl.api-3.0.0  from maven repository  to used core library to handle jsp efficiently. Its in lib folder of dynamic web project.
followed the instruction provided by chatgpt.
I can  perform this coding tasks   without using this jar file  but i wants to do it using this api jar file so it helps to handle jsp efficiently .how can i fix it
